# How to install CentOs 5.8 on 3TB disk with RAID 1 on Hetzner EX 4S (10 TB) server?

Tags: centos, raid, partition, parted

I have installed centos 5.8 with Hetzner server rescue mode but its disk parttion table is in MSDOS formate which does not support more than 2 TB space of disk so i need to change the partition table into GPT formate.but enable to install os in Gpt formate how can i cange parttion table formate from dos to gpt.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Boot using RescueCD from Hetzner.

```
parted /dev/sda
mkpart primary 1MB 512MB
set 1 boot on
parted /dev/sda
mkpart primary 512MB -1MB    
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
```

And next create LVMs, format partition and use VNC instalation.

Comment: What does this have to do with using a GPT partition or getting partition sizes larger than 2 TB?

Answer (score 2):

You don't. GPT support is available on EL6, but not on EL5.

So Hetzner should never have offered you this distribution.

To resolve the issue, install CentOS 6 instead.