# Changing partition table, Centos 6.3 on Hetzner Server

Tags: centos6, partition-table

I got from Hetzner a Server with Centos 6.3 + Plesk (2x3TB Software Raid 1), but the disk partition table is in MS-DOS format with no support for more than 2TB partitions.

I want to change the partition table into GPT format to get one big partition (and keep the software raid).

```
/dev/sdb1               1        1045     8388608+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb2            1045        1110      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3            1110      134785  1073741824+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb4          134785      364802  1847607768    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5          134785      364802  1847606744   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 8589 MB, 8589922304 bytes
Disk /dev/md1: 536 MB, 536858624 bytes
Disk /dev/md3: 1891.9 GB, 1891949166592 bytes (contains only /home, its empty)
Disk /dev/md2: 1099.5 GB, 1099511488512 bytes
```

Can someone help me with a guide? I am not a newbie, but this time I am confused about this.

Comment: Contact Hetzner and tell them to set up the server _properly_ this time.

Comment: Didn't...didn't this question get asked a few days ago?

Comment: Have them set up LARA KVM-over-IP with an OS install disk and install it the way you want....

Comment: @tombull89 [Not exactly.](http://serverfault.com/a/470654/126632)

Comment: @Michael Hampton, before I have post here I asked hetzner, they told me CentOS need that disk partition table in MS-DOS format.

Comment: In that case, either find someone at Hetzner who knows what they're talking about, or take your money elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hetzner has a good tutorial how to partition and install a server with the rescue system and  installimage http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Installimage

Comment: Nice idea, to bad that installimage is this time not useful it needs that msdos partion to install.

Comment: I complained to Hetzner about installimage's limitation of not supporting GPT a while ago and they said they were working on adding GPT support but it might be a while. Meanwhile you can edit a local copy and make the needed changes (if you're brave); it's just a perl script.